# How to import / read PKCS#12 pfx with Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pkcs#12

I have a file based .pfx certificate file containing a certificate and private key.

I would like to import / load it to an Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate using BC.

I am able to load it with .NET like this:

`var cert2 = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\temp\cert.pfx");`

However, I don't want to use the built-in .NET classes for cryptography, the above statement is insanely slow on Windows and kicks off e.g. GPU calculations and spikes my CPU.

Comment: A private key cannot be imported into an `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate`. Technically, this is because no private key is encapsulated (as can also be seen from the source code). Ultimately, this is because X.509 certificates themselves do not contain a private key (since they only bind the public key to an identity). Microsoft's `X509Certificate2` is not the rule here, but the exception. A .pfx file can be loaded with C#/BouncyCastle e.g. with `Pkcs12Store#Load()`.

Comment: Got it, thanks. You could write this as the solution....