# .NET poor performance of X509Certificate2 and RSA

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate, rsa, bouncycastle, kestrel-http-server

I'm working on a cross platform multi-tenant application with dynamic SSL certificates. Initially, I was using the .NET RSA functions, but since they're not cross platform I switched that portion to Bouncy Castle. When I did that I noticed that the BC performance was *substantially* better than the .NET RSA performance. I would have guesstimated BC to be at least 3-5x slower because it's .NET and not running natively on the platform, but that was not the case.

Now I'm having to dynamically load SSL certificates into Kestrel. The only method I have found to do so is to pass it a X509Certificate2. In this example it is built from a certificate file and a private key file on disk using Microsoft's "custom" RSACertificate2:

```
  var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(publicKeyPath, privateKeyPath);
```

As can be seen in these two questions, I've already explored options to replace it with BC due to its impact on performance.

[How to attach a private key to a certificate using Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638890/how-to-attach-a-private-key-to-a-certificate-using-bouncy-castle)

[How to import / read PKCS#12 pfx with Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638690/how-to-import-read-pkcs12-pfx-with-bouncy-castle)

Right now I can only see switching away from Kestrel or opening a bug report with Microsoft as options. So my question is if anyone has suggestions?

For whatever it is worth, I suspect that the X509Certificate2 might use the RSA class, and the RSA class seems prone to create a new key when the class is created after which the new key is overwritten. So the huge performance difference (up to 200x) could be due to the Microsoft classes creating new RSA keys. But it's just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I'm having to dynamically load SSL certificates into Kestrel. The only method I have found to do so is to pass it a X509Certificate2.

That is correct.  The .NET components that use TLS/SSL will only ever use the system TLS library.  The Windows TLS provider (SChannel) only works with Windows certificates and the Windows certificate store.  .NET X509Certificate2, on Windows, is backed by a Windows CERT_CONTEXT, so it can be used for TLS.  Bouncy Castle's certificates are not, so they can't be.

> var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(publicKeyPath, privateKeyPath);

This will actually load the private key as an ephemeral key (equivalent to loading a PFX with X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet).  But, as part of its out-of-process key management, SChannel requires that the private key be stored/named.  You might find that you need to change the cert to a temporary-persisted ("perphemeral") private key with something like

```
byte[] pfx = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
cert.Dispose();
cert = new X509Certificate2(pfx);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried the PFX but performance is still a problem.